# Vue3: update arrays to input

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, input, vuejs3

I have two inputs to users select a option in array

==> input one: [ orange, green, yellow ]
==> input two: [ orange, green, yellow ]

I need update the second array after user select some option in the first array. Example user select "green" in first input

==> input one: "green" (selected)
==> input two: [orange, yellow] (without option selected in the first array)

I don't know how to do that using Vue3. I am new here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use computed property and filter for remaining items:

```js
const { ref, computed } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  // COMPOSITION API
  setup() {
    const items = ref([ 'orange', 'green', 'yellow' ])
    const selected = ref(null)
    const selected2 = ref(null)
    
    const remainItems = computed(() => items.value.filter(i => !i.includes(selected.value)))
    
    return { items, selected, selected2, remainItems }
  }
  // OPTIONS API
  /*data() {
    return {
      items: [ 'orange', 'green', 'yellow' ],
      selected: null,
      selected2: null
    };
  },
  computed: {
    remainItems() {
      return this.items.filter(i => !i.includes(this.selected))
    }
  }*/
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.29/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div>Selected: {{ selected }}</div>
  <select v-model="selected">
    <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
    <option v-for="item in items">{{item}}</option>
  </select>
  <div>Selected: {{ selected2 }}</div>
  <select v-model="selected2">
    <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
    <option v-for="item in remainItems">{{item}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: how can I give you my best recomendations, should I click in somewhere ?
and if I am not being so abuse, can you explain composition api format?

Comment: Check now pls I updated my answer

Comment: well, in the compositing API it seems more understandable, awesome... thanks again! Nicola, you saving my life today, really.. Now maybe I will get a job, I am doind a test tomorrow about vue3 composition api and doing some exercices!

Comment: You are welcome :) feel free to ask for help if you need, I am ready to try to assist if I can :)

Comment: hi, its me again... I have another test a little more complex... It´s like the example before but with 5 options to input, not only 2... The problem is if I use your code, copy and past 3 more select options, I can repeat colors just starting filling from last to first.
I was trying create another array but I fail...
can you help me again?
sorry if I am abuse...

Comment: Hey Fernanda, please create another question with little more details (how many elements in array with options? ),  and I will try to help you :)

Comment: hi Nikola, I already create a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71389145/vue3-arrays-and-select-options

I am a little lost in Stackoverflow... sorry