# Selecting mutually exclusive options among multiple select components in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

There are 5 unique values to the `options` variable to the vue component. I would like the user to chose only 1 value for every select options I give. i.e. I have 5 input `select` components, I want the user to select just 1 value in each component which **cannot** by used by other `select` component.

For e.g.

```
input one: [ orange, green, yellow, black, blue ] 
input two: [ orange, green, yellow, black, blue ] 
input tree: [ orange, green, yellow, black, blue ] 
input four: [ orange, green, yellow, black, blue ] 
input five: [ orange, green, yellow, black, blue ]
```

If user selects orange in input one, the user cannot select orange again in inputs 2 to 5.

I have tried creating 2 arrays by maintaining itemSelected[] and itemsAvailable[], however I am unable to solve the issue.

How do I solve this issue in `Vue 3`?

Comment: Since you are new contributor, here are some tips: 
1. Try to be more general while asking the question: What does input options mean? what are the input 1 to 5? how are they coming in? using a select component?
2.  Try to add your code to that other programmers can take a gist of what you want and try to do.
3. Lastly, at least from my perspective,  I did not understand your question, try to edit it and explain like you are explaining a day 1 programmer as to what you are trying to achieve. Removing options selected in other inputs? What do you mean?
Are you trying multiple radio buttons?

Comment: thanks... for example: if user select on input two the color Black, the others inputs should remove this option color. I am trying use a array filter but I am new on this.. I know this is a little complex for me but it´s a test for a job and am broke my head today to solve that....

Comment: Hey, I have updated the question, feel free to correct me if there is any miscommunication.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much, you make it better for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create component for selection, and pass needed values as params:

```js
const { ref, computed, watch } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const items = ref(['orange', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'purple'])
    const getItems = computed(() => 
      items.value.filter(i => !selected.value.includes(i))
    )
    
    const selected = ref([])
    const getSelected = (val) => { 
      if(!selected.value.includes(val)) selected.value.push(val) 
    }
    
    const reseted = ref(false)
    const reset = () => {
      selected.value = []
      reseted.value = true
    }
    
    return { items, selected, getSelected, getItems, reset, reseted }
  }
})
app.component('selComp', {
  template: `
    <div :style="{color: selected}">Selected {{ idx + 1 }}: {{ selected }}</div>
    <select v-model="selected" @change="setSelected($event)">
      <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
      <option v-for="item in items" :key="item">{{ item }}</option>
    </select>
  `,
  props: ['items', 'idx', 'reseted'],
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const selected = ref(null)
    const setSelected = (e) => { emit('select', e.target.value) }
    
    watch(() => props.reseted, () => {
      selected.value = null
      emit('cleared')
    })
    
    return { selected, setSelected }
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```css
.cont{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.29/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div class="cont">
    <div v-for="(item, i) in items.length" :key="i">
      <sel-comp :items="getItems" :idx="i" :reseted="reseted" 
        @select="getSelected" @cleared="reseted=false">
      </sel-comp>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>{{ selected }}</p>
  <button @click="reset">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks Nikola, you helped me again... I really appreciate your help. I would like to talk to you on telegram or other means..
About the code, is there any way to put the selected option inside 'sel-comp' and not inside 'paragraph' ?
I think I'm going to give up being a programmer, I can't get to that level.

Comment: Hi Nikola, 

I don´t understand how to put the files insides the tag´s conventional <Template> and
< Script>..
can you help me only for this?

sorry to be boring about it...

Comment: Hey Fernanda :) I made you [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fernandas-selects-nv94mz?file=/src/components/selComp.vue)  take a look and tell me if you want more clarification , I can put comments in code , cheers :)

Comment: thank you Nikola... Now I understand well... :)

Comment: Hi Nikola. I found I little "bug" in your code. I promiss this is my last time to ask you revise your code...
the "bug" is, if user change the color in one selected option, the array [selected] still push the old and the new option selected... for example, in "select one" the user select "green" and than change to "orange". The array [selected] register the 2 color options and I don´t know how send it to backend.... I dont know if I was clear... This is my last one ask you, I promiss...

Comment: I was thinking maybe we "block" user to make changes after select one option and forced him click in "reset" button to restart select, what do you think?

Comment: Hey Fernanda, I corrected [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fernandas-selects-nv94mz?file=/src/App.vue) so take a look, cheers :)

Comment: many thanks, Nikola... Look, I told to my partner that I meet you here and we will sent you a email tomorrow about jobs, it´s ok for you? We are from Brazil...

Comment: Hello Nikola, we just sent a email by your website. Please, give us a return...thanks

Comment: @Fernanda Castanho hey, sure,  will write you back as soon as I get your e-mail, cheers :)

Comment: we already sent you a email... by your contact page in your website!!

Comment: hmm, I didn't receive it, maybe to send to email address from [here](https://github.com/nijepa)

Comment: Hi Nikola, please, check your email! tks!